# PowerShell Script to remove a set of file from multiple users' startup folders

Tags: powershell

The thing I'm failing to accomplish is getting the script to only delete items in the folder of the user currently logged in. The script works deleting everything in all of the users folders.

Here's the script:

```
Remove-Item 'C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\CRAP*' -Include *.kti, *.auc -Recurse
```

Comment: You need to determine the current logged-on user and replace the wildcard with the user's home folder.

Comment: So you want `Remove-Item "$env:USERPROFILE\AppData\Local\CRAP*" -include *.kti, *.auc -Recurse`?

Comment: "*The script works deleting everything in all of the users folders.*" - how? Users can't normally see into other user's appdata folders. It shouldn't find anything to delete except in the current user's folder, and maybe C:\Users\Public

Answer (score 0):

you could do..

```
Remove-Item "$env:LOCALAPPDATA" -Include *.kti, *.auc -Recurse
```

make sure to use -WhatIf first to see what it's going to delete..

```
Remove-Item "$env:LOCALAPPDATA" -Include *.kti, *.auc -Recurse -WhatIf
```